# How to center a small border at the bottom of an element using :before and :after?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to create a small border under my headlines on a website. I am doing it using before and after pseudo-elements. The code is a bit particular because I am adapting the code of the template I'm using. It is like this [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmxte361/)

The problem is the "left: 48%;" property : I have set it manually, but depending on the size of the screen, it might be centered or not, so it is not responsive. Is there a way to have the border always centered under the text ?

```css
.headline p:before,
.headline p:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  content: "";
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <h3>
    My title
  </h3>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you underlining the paragraph? Shouldn't that be set on the `.headline` instead?

Comment: What if the text is long? You want the underline to remain at 70px?

Comment: Yes the underline must remain the same size, and it is on the paragraph because that's how the theme is made, and I'm trying not to change too much code from the theme

Comment: What if the theme is wrong? If you add text to the paragraph, the underline will appear at the end of the text. If that's what you're after, good. If not, just keep in mind that it can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `calc()` css function as follows:

```css
.headline p:before,
.headline p:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 35px);
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  content: "";
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <h3>My title</h3>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Give the pseudoelement a `left` and `right` property - and then use `margin: auto` to center.

```css
.headline p:before,
.headline p:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  content: "";
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <h3>
    My title
  </h3>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1nqfxgk/)

Comment: @mplungjan - added

Answer (score 1):

**Use margin property**

Rewrite your code as

```
.headline p:before, .headline p:after {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70px;
border-bottom: 3px solid black;
content: "";
}
```

```css
.headline p:before,
.headline p:after {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  content: "";
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <h3>
My title
</h3>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use **margin:auto**

```css
.headline p:before,
.headline p:after {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  content: "";
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <h3>
    My title
  </h3>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```